# pydantic: incorrect deserialization when the class field is typed by a parent class

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, pydantic

The following code try to serialize the instance of `C` to dict and then deserialize back to `C` again. Because type information of `data` is lost in serialization process in `dict()`, the `data` instance is interpreted as an instance of `A` instead of `B` (my expectation).

I want `c_again` and `c` match each other. How can I do this?

```py
from typing import Tuple, List
from pydantic import BaseModel

class A(BaseModel):
    a: int

class B(A):
    b: float

class C(BaseModel):
    data: A

b = B(a=1, b=0.2)
c = C(data=b)
c_again = C(**c.dict())
print(c, ", ", c_again)
assert c == c_again
```

output

```
data=B(a=1, b=0.2) ,  data=A(a=1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/h-ishida/tmp/tmp.py", line 18, in <module>
    assert c == c_again
AssertionError
```

Comment: Why not data: B?

Comment: There are many other subclass `D`, `E` ... which inheritting from `A`, and I want let `C` accept any of these subclasses. To avoid complexity I wrote `data: A` in this question, but in my actual use case data is `data: Tuple[A, ...]`

Comment: You sure it is Tuple not Union?

Answer (score 0):

Building up on @bc291 's comment:

What you need as a starting point is to type-hint `data` as a `Union` of several possible types, in your example `data: Union[A, B]`. But that won't be enough: if you do only that, pydantic will try to match your data to the first type it can complete, so it would still instantiate `c_again.data` as `A(a=1)`, ignoring the `b` key/attribute. You could work around this by type-hinting `B` first in the union, like `Union[B, A]`, that works but it would be neither elegant nor robust, especially if your actual use case involves many subclasses like you said.

So, you also need to add a `Config` to `A` that will make pydantic refuse to instantiate it if `b` is present, so it will skip it and instantiate a class of the `Union` that matches all the keys/attributes instead (in this case, `B`). Note that sublasses of A will inherit this behaviour.

```py
from typing import Union
from pydantic import BaseModel


class A(BaseModel):
    a: int

    class Config:
        extra = 'forbid'


class B(A):
    b: float


class C(BaseModel):
    data: Union[A, B]


b = B(a=1, b=0.2)
c = C(data=b)
c_again = C(**c.dict())
print(c, ", ", c_again)
assert c == c_again
```

Output:

```
data=B(a=1, b=0.2) ,  data=B(a=1, b=0.2)
# no assertion error
```